# Microservices architecture for a system using multiple content providers

Tags: spring, architecture, microservices

We have a huge monolithic application which talks to multiple providers for content.
Each of these providers have different API contracts but the overall schema is almost similar.
Right now we are using command design pattern and transforming responses from each provider into a common schema for our frontend.

What should be the right approach is deciding modules for our microservices.
As should we break them down via business logic or per provider or both business logic + provider.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I consider individual deployability to be corner-stone of the microservices. All features of microservices can be traced back to individual deployability.

That being said the idea is to decompose business functions in such a way that each of the module remains individual deployable. A module in my opinion should own all interaction with all possible vendors - encompassing its complete business domain.

Second chapter of Sam Newman's book [Monolith to Microservices](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/monolith-to-microservices/9781492047834/ch02.html#idm46387402885464) expands on this area.